# mutilThread ios

Tags: ios, multithreading, alassetslibrary

My application's function is  to transfer the pics between two iDevices.

The user can choose lots of pic to send.  But since the send process need time, so right now I just put the pics that have not yet been sent into an array when the user picks it from the photo-library.

My problem now is that if the user selects too many pics at one time my application will be terminated abruptly.  My solution now is that if the user selects too many pics at one time all I will just place marks on some pics but leave them in photo-library, while also putting them into the array.  Then I have another thread to load the pics from the library at the same time the sending action happened.  So my point here is I'm doubting that so many pics had been put into the array one time is the reason the application is terminating, so i want put some pics cached then left some others in disk, my code:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag == 100)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            inArray = YES;
            NSLog(@"---------%d",[self.imageArr count]);
            if ([self.imageArr count] < kCachedImages) {
                [self.imageArr addObject:thisImageObj];
                [thisImageObj release];
            }
            else
            [self.imageURLArr addObject:photoURL];

            if(!isSending)
            {
                currentPos = -1;
                [self sendImage];
            }
            [sndTableView reloadData];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 2)
        {
            if (inArray) {
                if ([self.imageArr count] < kCachedImages) {
                    [self.imageArr addObject:thisImageObj];
                    [thisImageObj release];
                }else {
                    [self.imageURLArr addObject:photoURL];
                }
            }else {
                [self.imageArr addObject:thisImageObj];
            }

           if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
               [self.popOverView dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            }
           else {
               [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
           }


            [sndTableView reloadData];
            if(!isSending)
            {
                currentPos = -1;
                [self sendImage];
            }
        }

    }

}


- (void)sendImage
{
    if(![self.imageArr count])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
        isSending = NO;
        [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];
        return; //end of all sending
    }


    NSMutableData *toBeSend = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:sizeof(packetHeader)+kBuffer];
    imageObj *imgObj;
    if ([self.imageArr count]) {
        imgObj = [[self.imageArr objectAtIndex:0]retain];
    }

  //here created another thread to load pics from library  
    if ([self.imageURLArr count] > 0) {
                         [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(load) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    }


    packetHeader header;
    header.magic = 0x5577ACAC;
    header.seq = currentSeq++;

    if(currentPos < 0) //first packet
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgObj.pimage];
        self.currentSendingImg.image = img;

        //thumbnail
        img = [TransferViewController imageWithImage:img scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(70, 70)];
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5);

        header.command = 16;
        header.commandData1 = imgObj.imageSize;
        header.commandData2 = (imgObj.imageWidth<<16) + imgObj.imageLength;
        header.commandData3 = [data length];
//      NSLog(@"thumbnail data length = %u", header.commandData3);
        [toBeSend appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:&header length:sizeof(packetHeader)]];
        [toBeSend appendData:data];
        currentPos = 0;
        isSending = YES;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
        [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        if(currentPos + kBuffer < imgObj.imageSize)
        {
            header.command = 19;
            header.commandData1 = kBuffer;
            [toBeSend appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:&header length:sizeof(packetHeader)]];
            NSRange r;
            r.location = currentPos;
            r.length = kBuffer;
            [toBeSend appendData:[imgObj.pimage subdataWithRange:r]];
            currentPos += kBuffer;
        }
        else
        {//last packet
            header.command = 17;
            header.commandData1 = imgObj.imageSize - currentPos;
            [toBeSend appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:&header length:sizeof(packetHeader)]];
            NSRange r;
            r.location = currentPos;
            r.length = header.commandData1;
            [toBeSend appendData:[imgObj.pimage subdataWithRange:r]];
            currentPos = -1;
            if ([self.imageArr count]) {
                [self.imageArr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            }
            [self.sndTableView reloadData];
        }
    }

    [manager sendPacket:toBeSend];
    self.sendingProgess.progress = (float)currentPos / (float)imgObj.imageSize;

    [imgObj release];
}


- (void)load 
{


    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    if (![imageURLArr count]) {
        return;
    }        
    int imageSum = [imageURLArr count];

        NSURL *path = [self.imageURLArr objectAtIndex:0] ;

        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library assetForURL:path resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
         {
             ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
             CGImageRef ref = [representation fullResolutionImage];
             if (ref != nil) {
                 omg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
                 [omg retain];
             }

         }
                failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
         {
             // error handling
         }];
        [library release];

        if (omg) {
            NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(omg, kcompressionQuality);
            thisImageObj = [imageObj alloc];
            thisImageObj.imageSize = [data length];
            thisImageObj.imageWidth = omg.size.width;
            thisImageObj.imageLength = omg.size.height;
            thisImageObj.pimage = data;
            [omg release];
        }
        else {
            return;
        }


    imageSum--;

    if ([self.imageURLArr count]) {
        [self.imageURLArr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [self.imageArr addObject:thisImageObj];
    [thisImageObj release];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];

    [pool release];

}
```

but the method in other thread dosent work now,and the terminated problem still ,so could someone can give me some suggestions about how can i do,or i dont need another thread at all

Comment: UIImageJPEGRepresentation() is your problem.  UIKit and threads are mortal enemies.

Comment: I tried to clean up your text, but it's still just about impossible to say what your question is.

Comment: sorry for my question isn't clear enough,i have a mutable array which hold the pics,but the app will crash if the pics too much,my solution is put some pics in this array,left others right in the library,then the send and the loadimages acted simutaneously but in different thread ,well,the solution isn't work now

Comment: @CodaFi, `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` no longer requires that it be run on the main thread. Much of UIKit has been runnable on background threads since iOS4. Only drawing into the current view context and a few explicitly documented functions must be run on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues here at first glance. First, you're using                          `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`, which is almost never the right tool. This can generate an unbounded number of threads. This probably isn't what's crashing you, but it's a very dangerous practice. The better solution is something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
  [self load];
};
```

This will correctly manage your thread pool.

Your main problem is that you're accessing your ivars without any locking. `NSMutableArray` is not thread safe. You can't just modify it on any thread. GCD helps here, too. Mike Ash did a good write up called [What's New in GCD.](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-14-whats-new-in-gcd.html) You can use `dispatch_sync` to read and `dispatch_barrier_async` to write.

All that said, make certain you really need this background thread. What's taking so long in `load`? When you can avoid threads, you generally should.